# Magento 2.2: Custom product attribute get

Tags: magento2.2, product-attribute

How to get Custom product attribute in custom phtml file in magento 2.2.2

Example Like Product Attribute

(1) Nouveauté

(2) Meilleure vente

This is my custom phtml file magento 1.9 so how to use in magento 2.2.2

```
<?php
/**
 * Product list template
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
 */
?>
<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>

<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>
<section id="section-products">
    <h3 class="title-type-01">
        <span><?php echo $this->__('Ours products') ?></span>
    </h3>
    <ul class="product-list">
        <?php
            $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count();
            $_columnCount    = $this->getColumnCount();
            $i               = 1;
            foreach ($_productCollection as $_product):
        ?>
        <li<?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?> class="last"<?php endif; ?>>
            <div class="stamps">
            <?php if($_product->getNouveaute()): ?>
                <span class="stamp new">Nouveauté</span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if($_product->getMeilleureVente()): ?>
                <span class="stamp best">Meilleure vente</span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <?php if(!$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
            <span class="stamp out-stock">Rupture de stock</span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if($_product->getSpecialPrice()): ?>
            <span class="stamp sale">Promotion</span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <a class="picture" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(283,172); ?>" alt="" />
            </a>
            <div class="caption">
                <div class="in">
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="name"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a>

                    <?php if($_product->getTypeId() == 'configurable' || !$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>" class="btn-type-02"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></a>
                    <?php else: ?>
                    <form action="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form_<?php echo $i; ?>">
                        <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="btn-type-02" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this,'<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>');return false;" />
                    </form>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="details">
                <p class="price"><?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?></p>
                <p class="availability">
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </p>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
                var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form_<?php echo $i; ?>');
                productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
                    if (this.validator.validate()) {
                        var form = this.form;
                        var oldUrl = form.action;

                        if (url) {
                           form.action = url;
                        }
                        var e = null;
                        //Start of our new ajax code
                        if(!url){
                            url = jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').attr('action');
                        }
                        var data = jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').serialize();
                        data += '&isAjax=1';
                        try {
                            jQuery.ajax({
                                  url: url,
                                  dataType: 'json',
                                  type : 'post',
                                  data: data
                            });
                            jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow', function(){
                                jQuery('#top-nav .tooltip').animate({opacity: 1, top: '45px'})
                                jQuery('#top-nav a.cart').animate({color: '#93b51a'});

                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    jQuery('#top-nav .tooltip').animate({opacity: 0, top: '-45px'})
                                    jQuery('#top-nav a.cart').animate({color: '#fff'});
                                }, 3000);
                            });
                            frontCartIncrement();
                        } catch (e) {
                        }
                        this.form.action = oldUrl;
                        if (e) {
                            throw e;
                        }

                        if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                            button.disabled = true;
                        }
                    }
                }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

                productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
                    if(this.validator) {
                        var nv = Validation.methods;
                        delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
                        delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
                        delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
                        // Remove custom datetime validators
                        for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                            if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                                delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                            }
                        }

                        if (this.validator.validate()) {
                            if (url) {
                                this.form.action = url;
                            }
                            this.form.submit();
                        }
                        Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
                    }
                }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
            //]]>
            </script>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</section>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What are the attribute codes of the above attributes ?

Comment: do you want it in category page?

Comment: cms home page get product list

Answer (score 0):

```
$_product = $block->getProduct();

$myattribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('Your_Attribute_Code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

echo $myattribute;
```